# display entire array after moving values of it to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array containing objects where there is a `rpId` key in some of the objects. The goal is to separate/move the objects that return undefined to a separate array and remove them out of the first array.

e.g.:
`results = [{id: 1}, {id: 2, rpId: 1076}, {id: 3}, {id: 4, rpId: 303}];`

goal: `results = [{id: 2, rpId: 1076}, {id: 4, rpId: 303}]` and `stations = [{id: 1}, {id: 3}]`

My current approach can be seen below. As visible, I get a wrong array1 because it contains an object with a rpId, plus array2 returns the keys of the object and I'd like to read the entire object, not just the "undefined" of the key.

```
const array1 = [{id: 1}, {id: 2, rpId: 1076}, {id: 3}, {id: 4, rpId: 303}];
const array2 = [];

const mapping = array1.map((e) => e.rpId);
console.log("mapping",mapping);

mapping.forEach(function(elem, index){
    elem === undefined ? array2.push(elem) && array1.splice(index, elem === undefined) && console.log(elem): console.log("defined", elem);
}),

console.log("1", array1); // [{ id: 2, rpId: 1076 }, { id: 3 }]
console.log("2", array2); // [undefined, undefined]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the `rpId` property is undefined in each element.

```js
const array1 = [{id: 1}, {id: 2, rpId: 1076}, {id: 3}, {id: 4, rpId: 303}];
const array2 = [];

array1.forEach(function(elem, index){
    if(elem.rpId === undefined) 
      array2.push(elem) && array1.splice(index, 1)
});
console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

One can also use `Array#filter` or push elements into two separate arrays based on the condition for better performance.

```js
const array1 = [{id: 1}, {id: 2, rpId: 1076}, {id: 3}, {id: 4, rpId: 303}];
const yes = [], no = [];
array1.forEach(elem=>(elem.rpId!==undefined?yes:no).push(elem));
console.log(yes);
console.log(no);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter too:

```
let results = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2, rpId: 1076 },
    { id: 3 },
    { id: 4, rpId: 303 },
  ];

  const stations = results.filter((c) => !c.rpId);

  results = results.filter((c) => c.rpId);

  console.log("stations", stations);
  console.log("results", results);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const GiveItACreativeName = (arr) => {
  const result = []
  const stations = []
  arr.forEach((el) => {
    if('rpId' in el) result.push(el);
    else stations.push(el);
  });
  return {result, stations}
}
console.log(
  GiveItACreativeName([{id: 1}, {id: 2, rpId: 1076}, {id: 3}, {id: 4, rpId: 303}])
);
```